# Updated .gitignore & also reset git cache but the directory is not ignored by git

Tags: git, github

In my project directory, there is a directory called `docker/`, under which there's another directory `volumes/`, under which there are sub-directories. The directory structure is like:

```
my-project/
    - docker/
        - volumes/
            - data/
               ...
            - other-data/
               ...
.gitignore
```

I need git to ignore everything under directory `docker/volumes/` since there are large files under it. Since I already committed `.gitignore` , now I need to update `.gitignore` . So, I opened `.gitignore` & updated it to:

```
...
docker/volumes/*
```

After saved it. I run:

`git rm -r --cache .`

Then, I `git add .` & run `git commit -m "update gitignore & reset cache"`.

Then, I `git push origin master`

But I still get error:

```
remote: error: Trace: 103f63186285fad8994c61ba22338c97bb63f7d3a31c782e4a20f0a837bf73b3
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File docker/volumes/data/default/00000000000000000000.snapshots is 256.00 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File docker/volumes/other-data/default/00000000000000000000.events is 256.00 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
```

I mean I should have already asked git to ignore everything under `docker/volumes/`, or aren't I?

Comment: Have you added/committed it before adding it to the `.gitignore`?

Comment: Yes, like I said I have committed `.gitignore` before that's why I later have run `git rm -r --cache .` to reset cache in order to have updated `.gitignore` take effect.

Comment: The use of `git rm` affects *future* commits. *Past* commits—those you already made, that have the large files in them—are still there in your repository, holding the large files. You'll need to replace or remove the *past* commits, which is nontrivial (but possible).

Comment: @torek does it only apply for large files? Because I have been using `git rm -r --cache .` all the time when updating already committed `.gitignore`, it has been working. I get very confused by what you said. Could you please further explain or provide reference?

Comment: Yes, in this particular case, it applies only for large files, because it's just the large files inside commits that are a problem for GitHub. See the linked duplicate. There are reasons it has 834 upvotes and 25 answers (at this time): there's way more to this than will fit in a comment.

Comment: @torek Thank you very much! I will check that. BTW, I have then tried https://git-lfs.github.com/ as an alternative option for large file handling, but for some reason it is not working for me either, I know it must be my problem not the tool, so I will post another question concerning my usage of that tool.

Comment: I'll note that I have not actually *used* LFS on GitHub: at a previous $work we tried an experiment with it but weren't thrilled with the result, and went a different way. (That was years ago now so it might have changed some since then, too.)